# How to make promises execute synchronously using generators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am following the blog article here : 
http://www.tivix.com/blog/making-promises-in-a-synchronous-manner

which says that generators could be used to synchronize promise execution.

I know it's a bad practice - we're using a GWT like framework (Urweb to be precise) which as of now understands only synchronous javascript function return values.

Following code taken from that article

```
{
  'use strict';

  let asyncTask = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      let delay = 1000;

      setTimeout(function () {
        resolve(delay);
      }, delay);
    });

  let makeMeLookSync = fn => {
    let iterator = fn();
    let loop = result => {
      !result.done && result.value.then(res =>
        loop(iterator.next(res)));
    };

    loop(iterator.next());
  };

  console.log(1);

  makeMeLookSync(function* () {
    let result = yield asyncTask();

    console.log(result);
  });

  console.log(3);
}
```

gives the following output :

`1
3
1000`

But if the promise was made synchronous, the output should have been

`1 
1000
3`

Am I doing it wrong ? Or is it not possible to make the promise synchronous using generators ?

Comment: The article is wrong. It lets your write asynchronous code in a sequential ("synchronous") manner without using `then`, it does not make promises synchronous (which is impossible). Btw, you get the same advantageous syntax using `async`/`await` in modern Js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing it wrong ?

Yes. All the code that should *appear* to be synchronous would have to go inside the generator function:

```
makeMeLookSync(function* () {
  let result = yield asyncTask();

  console.log(result);
  console.log(3);
});
```

> Or is it not possible to make the promise synchronous using generators ?

You can **never** make asynchronous code synchronous. Generators allow you to write code that *looks* synchronous, which means (and which is mentioned in the article you linked to) that the code is executed from top to bottom:

> To put it as simply as possible: async JavaScript does not execute as it reads - top to bottom.

But that only works inside the generator as I mentioned above. The `yield` keyword is what allows you to write the code in a synchronous fashion. Note that the name of the function is `makeMeLookSync`, not `makeMeSync`.

---

Having said that, ES2017 introduced [**`async` functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which basically do the same thing without generators and a runner to execute the generators:

```js
{
  'use strict';

  let asyncTask = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      let delay = 1000;

      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(delay);
      }, delay);
    });


  console.log(1);

  (async function() {
    let result = await asyncTask();
    console.log(result);
    console.log(3);
  }());
}
```